# rename / flatten dataframe using column values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to pandas and was wondering if there is an easy way to do this following transformation programmatically.

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015,2016],'srev':[1,2]})
```

=>

```
bar = pd.DataFrame({'srev_year_2015': [1],'srev_year_2016':[2]})
```

visually it looks like this:

foo:

[image]

bar:

[image]

Thank you!

**editted:**

I want to programmatically use the column names `srev` and `year` to name the new column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do `unstack`

```
s=foo.set_index('year').unstack().to_frame().T
s.columns=s.columns.map('{0[0]}_year_{0[1]}'.format) 
s
   srev_year_2015  srev_year_2016
0               1               2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `pivot_table`:

```
output = foo.pivot_table(columns='year')
```

Output:

```
year  2015  2016
srev     1     2
```

It won't give you the column names that you provide, but you can manually rename it and the index.

```
output.columns = [f'{output.index[0]}_{output.columns.name}_{col}' for col in output.columns]
output = output.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: thank you for you comment, I've updated my question: actually I want to use the column name `srev` and `year` to name the new column instead of hardcoded in this example. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Not sure I completely understand what you mean. I updated it, but I kind of doubt that's what you mean.